# 500 Internal Server Error and Win32 error 2148074244 (SEC_E_INTERNAL_ERROR) when authenticating webapp on IIS6

Tags: active-directory, iis-6, account

Environment:

1. MS Windows 2003 Server R2 SP2
2. Server is a member of domain
3. IIS 6, ASP.NET 1.1.4322
4. Web site security settings: Directory Security -> Authentication Methods - all checkboxes are unmarked except 'Integrated Windows authentication'.

Issue: got 500 Internal Server Error, when authenticating using Windows authentication using some AD account. Authenticating using different accounts is ok.

IIS log:

> 2010-12-02 08:02:33 W3SVC1 192.168.115.55 GET /FinancialAnalytics2010/default.aspx - 80 - 192.168.115.40 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+1.0.3705;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+InfoPath.2) 401 1 0
>
> 2010-12-02 08:02:33 W3SVC1 192.168.115.55 GET /FinancialAnalytics2010/default.aspx - 80 - 192.168.115.40 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+1.0.3705;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+InfoPath.2) 500 0 2148074244

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause: 'Log On To..' account attribure was defined for the user with the unsucessful authentication.

Resolution: check users account propeprties 'Logon Hours...' and 'Log On To...' and clear them if necessary.